# UITabBarControllerDelegate method is not running if I init UITabBarController with more than 5 ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController and I init it with 6 ViewControllers.

And i am running some other function inside UITabBarControllerDelegate method:

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
            animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                              toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
```

But when I change the tabBarController.selectedIndex between 1 to 5, the delegate method will be activated. When I change the tabBarController.selectedIndex between 5 and 6, the delegate method is not running.

Comment: AFAIK, the selectedIndex can never be higher than 4 - further view controllers are hidden behind an automatically generated 'More'-tab.

Comment: But we can hide the "More tab". I find that i have this problem only on iPhone iOS7.